# Javascript resizing of Firefox pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, popup

I'm just learning Javascript and jQuery, but I'm an HTML'r trying to take the next step..

I'm attempting to drop content into a table, which can be any size at all (It's for a news site). I check for size and then resize the popup accordingly; while the window isn't exactly right it works, but in Firefox it's not even resizing.

Using a generic link to pop-open a basic window:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://site.local/popup/','popup','width=1,height=1')">popup</a>
```

I'm pointing it to a default page where the cms is placing all content into a table (id="top"). It has a default width="1" to force a constraint, and then letting the content expand the table to set the real size. I then check the table size to see and resize the window on document.ready():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var divh = document.getElementById('top').offsetHeight;
  var divw = document.getElementById('top').offsetWidth;

  //Test size
  //alert("Table: width= " + divw + "px / height= " + divh +"px");

  //Resize
  window.resizeTo(divw,divh);
  }    
 -->
</script>
```

I need to be able to resize a window already opened in Firefox.

All the window sizes (except Firefox) are off but I can pad them - a little larger is better than cut-off. Firefox, unfortunately, generates a tiny 180w x 249h window and never resizes.

I've searched here unsuccessfully - most suggest editing a setting in firefox, which I clearly can't expect users to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't be assured that any browser will let you control the size of windows you create. You can't even be sure you'll get a window at all - people can instruct their browsers to open all new windows as browser tabs.

Comment: Agreed - sorry, I wasn't clear. I need Firefox to open to nearly the dimension requested in Javascript without having to ask the user to adjust his internal about:config settings

Comment: You were quite clear and Pointy is right: If the user has the "window resize" option turned off, then it's impossible to change the window size.

Comment: Yep - thought as much. Thanks Pointy & RoToRa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox comes with a preference for user to allow/disallow resizing of window using Javascript. It's in Tools - Options - Content - Enable Javascript -> [Advanced].

I am not sure if resizing is disabled by default, but you might want to check your own Firefox installation first.

If it's disabled by default, then unfortunately there is nothing you could do to resize the window after it has been opened. An ugly workaround would be to open itself once again using `window.open()` with the preferred size though.

Comment: Yep - that's what I was afraid of. I'll have to see if I can prefetch any image size and then set constraints for the banner dimensions, so I can make a more educated guess. Thanks all..

Comment: BTW, cnn.com/live use the ugly workaround I mentioned. For some reason they insist to open another pop-up if `window.name` does not match.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend replacing your popup with a div popup. You're going to run into issues like you have with Firefox, and browsers blocking it altogether.  Assuming you have jqueryui included and you're loading this content from the same domain:

```
$('#container').load('/popup',function() {
     var table = $('#container #top');
    $('#container').dialog({height:table.height(), width: table.width()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
<a class='poptrigger'>pop</a>

$(function(){
 var w = $("#top").outerWidth();
 var h = $("#top").outerHeight();
 $('.poptrigger').click(function{
  window.open('http://site.local/popup/','popup','width='+w+',height='+h)
 })
});
```

That way you shouldn't need to resize the window, but just set the size initially.

Comment: That would work if I knew the initial size. This is for a newspaper - the problem is that the internal elements can be any size, and any banner ad size can be attached. Images can accompany text before and after the element, and ad spaces on this popup can have skyscrapers as often as 320x240 square ads...I can only query a div/table in window that's already open to ascertain it's dimentions...really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not getting the content with ajax request and display it in a div above the current content?

Comment: Thanks - that's now under consideration in the organization. Seems "policies" may need to change before technology can work it's magic..