# In Firefox the window is not re-sizeing using JavaScript,

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a JavaScript to re-size all my popup windows:

```
function resize()
{
window.resizeTo(240,230);
}
```

But now it is not resizing in Mozilla Firefox, but it was doing earlier, also
or if the popup window is opened in a new tab, it is not resizing, also in some browsers it is not also. Is there any piece of JavaScript code which works in all scenarios and all browsers?

Comment: I don't know if it will work in this situation, but jQuery is often good at normalizing browser API and shimming in fixes for older browsers, so that code in one place will run everywhere.

Comment: No. Firefox has options to let users prevent scripts for resizing/moving windows. This is not something you can easily detect, and definitely can't override.

Answer (score 1):

> Firefox comes with a preference for user to allow/disallow resizing of
>   window using Javascript. It's in Tools - Options - Content - Enable
>   Javascript -> [Advanced].
>
> I am not sure if resizing is disabled by default, but you might want
>   to check your own Firefox installation first.
>
> If it's disabled by default, then unfortunately there is nothing you
>   could do to resize the window after it has been opened. An ugly
>   workaround would be to open itself once again using window.open() with
>   the preferred size though.

Source: [timdream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519617/timdream) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124400/javascript-resizing-of-firefox-pop-up-window))

I'll also add that:

> You can't be assured that any browser will let you control the size of
>   windows you create. You can't even be sure you'll get a window at all
>   - people can instruct their browsers to open all new windows as browser tabs

Source: [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) (same source as timdream)

Comment: That is not possible on any browser as far as I know. The tabs are usually the same size as the browser size. What is the goal you are trying to accomplish (why do you want to resize the browser window)? Maybe there's a way to do it without resizing it.